# force longtable to text width

Tags: tables, margins, longtable, textwidth

Instead of specifying the width of each column in a longtable (see below), is there a way to get it to automatically adjust its size so that it matches the text width, but does not go into the margins?

```
\floatsetup[longtable]{LTcapwidth=\textwidth}
\scriptsize 
\begin{longtable}[c] 
{p{0.045\textwidth}p{0.045\textwidth}p{0.045\textwidth}p{0.045\textwidth}p{0.045\textwidth}p{0.05\textwidth}p{0.045\textwidth}p{0.045\textwidth}p{0.045\textwidth}p{0.045\textwidth} p{0.045\textwidth} p{0.045\textwidth} p{0.045\textwidth}} 
\caption{Insert caption here}
\hline \multicolumn{13}{c} %Removed code for 13 column multiple page table%
 \end{longtable}
```

Comment: please extend your code snippet to complete document beginning with  `\documentclass...` and ending with `\end{document}`.  welcome to tex.se!

Comment: You might be interested in the `ltablex` package. Or you could use `\begin{longtable}[c]{*{13}{p{\dimexpr0.0768\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}}}` if all your 13 columns are equally wide.

Comment: @ leandriis, to my surprise, your suggestion (the same cross my mind)  doesn't give expected result. it might be due to number 13? :-).

Comment: There is also the `xltabular` package.

Comment: @Zarko: That's interesting. I just tried it and I get a table that is almost (99.8%) as wide as the textwidth: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sC5AK.png

Comment: @leandriis why not make it perfect (well, as perfect as TeX can) and use `*{13}{p{\dimexpr\textwidth/13-2\tabcolsep\relax}}`?

Comment: @leandriis, please provide an answer, that i can check/compare it with my experiments. using your suggestion, or suggestion of Skillmon, the results are almost the same and both gives shorter width of the table for about one column width. i use recent MikTeX (just updated).

Comment: @Zarko: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable}
\begin{document}
\scriptsize 
\begin{longtable}[c]{*{13}{p{\dimexpr0.0768\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}}} 
\caption{Insert caption here}
\endhead
1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13\\
\hline \multicolumn{13}{c}{test}
\end{longtable}
\end{document}` gives me the above posted result.

Comment: @leandriis thank you! Your suggestion of \begin{longtable}[c]{*{13}{p{\dimexpr0.0768\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}}} worked. I had to resize the font in a few cells, but otherwise great!

Comment: @leandriis, thank you. your code works. i wonder why my the very same didn't :-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This uses the same approach as Zarko and Skillmon, but uses a length register to avoid repeating the calculation 13 times.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{showframe}

\newlength{\mycolwidth}

\begin{document}
\scriptsize 
\setlength{\mycolwidth}{\dimexpr \textwidth/13 - 2\tabcolsep}%
\begin{longtable}[c]{*{13}{p{\mycolwidth}}}
\caption{Insert caption here}
\endfirsthead
\hline 
\multicolumn{13}{c}{Removed code for 13 column multiple page table}\\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

---

There is an automatic gap of `\tabcolsep` on the edges, which can be removed thusly.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{showframe}

\newlength{\mycolwidth}

\begin{document}
\scriptsize 
\setlength{\mycolwidth}{\dimexpr \textwidth - 24\tabcolsep}%
\divide \mycolwidth by 13

\begin{longtable}[c]{@{}*{13}{p{\mycolwidth}}@{}}
\caption{Insert caption here}
\endfirsthead
\hline 
\multicolumn{13}{c}{Removed code for 13 column multiple page table}\\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: now i wonder, what was wrong in my the very same code that doesn't give the same result as yours. overwriting my test code with yours solve my problem. apparently in it was some invisible character. +1 for nice working answer!