# How to make a longtable with a tabularx environment

Tags: tables, longtable

I am dealing with a table that does not fit in a single page. I do not know what to use, since I charged the package longtable but didn´t find the correct way to use it in this case.

Here is my preambule:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[letterpaper, left=2.4cm, right=2.4cm, top=2.4cm, bottom=2.4cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\renewcommand{\figurename}{Figura}
\renewcommand{\refname}{Referencias}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newlength\mylen
\settowidth\mylen{\textbf{Propuesta de}} % desired width of left-hand column
\usepackage{caption} 
\captionsetup[table]{skip=12pt}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{booktabs}    
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{tabenum}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[tabenum]{label*=\arabic*.,
                  leftmargin=*,
                  nosep,
                  before=\begin{minipage}{\hsize},
                  after=\end{minipage}}
\newlist{contenidos}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[contenidos]{label*=\arabic*.,
                     leftmargin=*,
                     nosep,
                     before=\begin{minipage}{\hsize},
                     after=\end{minipage}}
\newenvironment{mytabenum}
               {\begin{tabenum}[label*=\thecurrentcontenidos.\arabic*.]}
               {\end{tabenum}}
\newenvironment{mycontenidos}
               [1]
               {\begin{contenidos}[#1=contenidos] }
               {\setcounter{currentcontenidos}{\value{contenidosi}}\end{contenidos}}
               
\newcounter{currentcontenidos}
\usepackage{longtable}
```

And here is the code for my table (without the longtable environment):

```
\begin{table}
\caption{Relación de los contenidos con los objetivos didácticos de la Unidad Didáctica.}
\label{tab:Tabla 1}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} 
       >{\justifying\arraybackslash\parindent=0pt}X 
       >{\justifying\arraybackslash\parindent=0pt}X  @{}
       c}

\arrayrulecolor{green}
\toprule
\textbf{\textcolor{myGreen}{Criterios de Evaluación}} & \textbf{\textcolor{myGreen}{Estándares Aprendizaje}} & \textbf{\textcolor{myGreen}{Competencias Clave}} \\
\midrule
\arrayrulecolor{black}
\begin{mycontenidos}{series}
\item Reconocer las ecuaciones de los movimientos rectilíneo y circular, y aplicarlas a situaciones concretas. 
\end{mycontenidos} & 

\begin{mytabenum}
\item Obtiene las ecuaciones que describen la velocidad y la aceleración de un cuerpo a partri de la expresión del vector posición en función del tiempo.
\item Resuelve ejercicios prácticos de Cinemática en dos dimensiones (movimiento de un cuerpo en un plano), aplicando las ecuaciones del MRU y MRUA.
\end{mytabenum} & CMCT, CCL, CAA.
\\

\midrule
\begin{mycontenidos}{resume}
\item Interpretar representaciones gráficas de los movimientos rectilíneo y circular.
\end{mycontenidos}&

\begin{mytabenum}
\item Interpreta las gráficas que relacionan las variables implicadas en el MRU, MRUA y MCU, aplicando las ecuaciones adecuadas para obtener los valores del espacio recorrido, la velocidad y la aceleración.
\end{mytabenum} & CMCT, CCL, CAA.
\\
\midrule

\begin{mycontenidos}{resume}
\item Describir el MCUA y expresar la aceleración en función de sus componentes intrínsecas.
\end{mycontenidos}&

\begin{mytabenum}
\item Identifica las componentes intrínsecas de la aceleración en distintos casos prácticos y aplica las ecuaciones que permiten determinar su valor.
\end{mytabenum} & CMCT, CCL, CAA.
\\

\midrule

\begin{mycontenidos}{resume}
\item Relacionar en un movimiento circular las magnitudes angulares con las lineales. 
\end{mycontenidos}&

\begin{mytabenum}
\item Relaciona las magnitudes lineales y angulares para un móvil que describe unatrayectoria circular, estableciendo las ecuaciones correspondientes, y reconociendo situaciones cotidianas.
\end{mytabenum} & CMCT, CCL, CAA, CSC.
\\
\midrule

\begin{mycontenidos}{resume}
\item Identificar el movimiento no circular de un móvil en un plano como la composición de dos movimientos unidimensionales (MRU y MRUA). Utilizar aplicaciones virtuales interactivas de simulación de movimientos.
\end{mycontenidos}&

\begin{mytabenum}
\item Reconoce movimientos compuestos, establece las ecuaciones que los describen, calcula el valor de magnitudes como el alcance, la altura máxima, así como valores instantáneos de posición, velocidad y aceleración.
\item Resuelve problemas relativos a la composición de movimientos descomponiéndolos en dos movimientos rectilíneos.
\item Emplea simulaciones virtuales para resolver supuestos prácticos reales, determinando condiciones iniciales, trayectorias, y puntos de encuentro de los puntos implicados.
\end{mytabenum} & CCL, CAA.
\\
\bottomrule

\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
```

[image]

Comment: You have to load the `xltabular` package and use its eponymous environment. It brings the functionalities (and the syntax) of `longtable` to `tabularx`.

Comment: You can also compute the width needed.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/476199/force-longtable-to-text-width/476216?r=SearchResults&s=3|21.0607#476216 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16251/how-to-obtain-width-of-longtable/541959?r=SearchResults&s=1|30.8185#541959

Comment: Apart from switching to xltabular in order to allow page breaks inside of the table, I also suggest adjusting the column widths in order to reduce the amount of empty and "wasted" white space. Please also note that xltabular can only add a page break between two table rows (where your horizontal lines are) as opposed to within a table row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you could use `xltabular` to combine the features of `longtable` and `tabularx`. In the following MWE, I also included a second version of the table with slightly different column widths. With this layout you can wuite significantly reduce the amount of empty and "wasted" white space and also fit the whole table onto a single page:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[letterpaper, left=2.4cm, right=2.4cm, top=2.4cm, bottom=2.4cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\renewcommand{\figurename}{Figura}
\renewcommand{\refname}{Referencias}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newlength\mylen
\settowidth\mylen{\textbf{Propuesta de}} % desired width of left-hand column
\usepackage{caption} 
\captionsetup[table]{skip=12pt}
\usepackage{float}

\definecolor{green}{HTML}{66FF66}
\definecolor{myGreen}{HTML}{009900}

\usepackage{booktabs}    
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{tabenum}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[tabenum]{label*=\arabic*.,
                  leftmargin=*,
                  nosep,
                  before=\begin{minipage}{\hsize},
                  after=\end{minipage}}
\newlist{contenidos}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[contenidos]{label*=\arabic*.,
                     leftmargin=*,
                     nosep,
                     before=\begin{minipage}{\hsize},
                     after=\end{minipage}}
\newenvironment{mytabenum}
               {\begin{tabenum}[label*=\thecurrentcontenidos.\arabic*.]}
               {\end{tabenum}}
\newenvironment{mycontenidos}
               [1][resume]
               {\begin{contenidos}[#1=contenidos] }
               {\setcounter{currentcontenidos}{\value{contenidosi}}\end{contenidos}}
               
\newcounter{currentcontenidos}
\usepackage{xltabular}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\normalsize\bfseries\color{myGreen}}

\begin{document}


\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{@{} 
       >{\justifying\arraybackslash\parindent=0pt}X 
       >{\justifying\arraybackslash\parindent=0pt}X  
       c@{}}
\caption{Relación de los contenidos con los objetivos didácticos de la Unidad Didáctica.}
\label{tab:Tabla 1}\\
\arrayrulecolor{green}
\toprule
\thead{Criterios de Evaluación} & \thead{Estándares Aprendizaje} & \thead{Competencias Clave} \\
\midrule
\arrayrulecolor{black}
\endfirsthead
\arrayrulecolor{green}
\toprule
\thead{Criterios de Evaluación} & \thead{Estándares Aprendizaje} & \thead{Competencias Clave} \\
\midrule
\arrayrulecolor{black}
\endhead
\begin{mycontenidos}[series]
\item Reconocer las ecuaciones de los movimientos rectilíneo y circular, y aplicarlas a situaciones concretas. 
\end{mycontenidos} & 

\begin{mytabenum}
\item Obtiene las ecuaciones que describen la velocidad y la aceleración de un cuerpo a partri de la expresión del vector posición en función del tiempo.
\item Resuelve ejercicios prácticos de Cinemática en dos dimensiones (movimiento de un cuerpo en un plano), aplicando las ecuaciones del MRU y MRUA.
\end{mytabenum} & CMCT, CCL, CAA.
\\

\midrule
\begin{mycontenidos}
\item Interpretar representaciones gráficas de los movimientos rectilíneo y circular.
\end{mycontenidos}&

\begin{mytabenum}
\item Interpreta las gráficas que relacionan las variables implicadas en el MRU, MRUA y MCU, aplicando las ecuaciones adecuadas para obtener los valores del espacio recorrido, la velocidad y la aceleración.
\end{mytabenum} & CMCT, CCL, CAA.
\\
\midrule

\begin{mycontenidos}
\item Describir el MCUA y expresar la aceleración en función de sus componentes intrínsecas.
\end{mycontenidos}&

\begin{mytabenum}
\item Identifica las componentes intrínsecas de la aceleración en distintos casos prácticos y aplica las ecuaciones que permiten determinar su valor.
\end{mytabenum} & CMCT, CCL, CAA.
\\

\midrule

\begin{mycontenidos}
\item Relacionar en un movimiento circular las magnitudes angulares con las lineales. 
\end{mycontenidos}&

\begin{mytabenum}
\item Relaciona las magnitudes lineales y angulares para un móvil que describe unatrayectoria circular, estableciendo las ecuaciones correspondientes, y reconociendo situaciones cotidianas.
\end{mytabenum} & CMCT, CCL, CAA, CSC.
\\
\midrule

\begin{mycontenidos}
\item Identificar el movimiento no circular de un móvil en un plano como la composición de dos movimientos unidimensionales (MRU y MRUA). Utilizar aplicaciones virtuales interactivas de simulación de movimientos.
\end{mycontenidos}&

\begin{mytabenum}
\item Reconoce movimientos compuestos, establece las ecuaciones que los describen, calcula el valor de magnitudes como el alcance, la altura máxima, así como valores instantáneos de posición, velocidad y aceleración.
\item Resuelve problemas relativos a la composición de movimientos descomponiéndolos en dos movimientos rectilíneos.
\item Emplea simulaciones virtuales para resolver supuestos prácticos reales, determinando condiciones iniciales, trayectorias, y puntos de encuentro de los puntos implicados.
\end{mytabenum} & CCL, CAA.
\\
\bottomrule

\end{xltabular}

\newpage
{\setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}
\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{@{} 
       p{5cm} 
       X  
       >{\centering\arraybackslash}p{\widthof{\textbf{Competencias}}}@{}}
\caption{Relación de los contenidos con los objetivos didácticos de la Unidad Didáctica.}
\label{tab:Tabla 1}\\
\arrayrulecolor{green}
\toprule
\thead{Criterios de Evaluación} & \thead{Estándares Aprendizaje} & \thead{Competencias\\ Clave} \\
\midrule
\arrayrulecolor{black}
\endfirsthead
\arrayrulecolor{green}
\toprule
\thead{Criterios de Evaluación} & \thead{Estándares Aprendizaje} & \thead{Competencias\\ Clave} \\
\midrule
\arrayrulecolor{black}
\endhead
\begin{mycontenidos}[series]
\item Reconocer las ecuaciones de los movimientos rectilíneo y circular, y aplicarlas a situaciones concretas. 
\end{mycontenidos} & 

\begin{mytabenum}
\item Obtiene las ecuaciones que describen la velocidad y la aceleración de un cuerpo a partri de la expresión del vector posición en función del tiempo.
\item Resuelve ejercicios prácticos de Cinemática en dos dimensiones (movimiento de un cuerpo en un plano), aplicando las ecuaciones del MRU y MRUA.
\end{mytabenum} & CMCT, CCL, CAA.
\\

\midrule
\begin{mycontenidos}
\item Interpretar representaciones gráficas de los movimientos rectilíneo y circular.
\end{mycontenidos}&

\begin{mytabenum}
\item Interpreta las gráficas que relacionan las variables implicadas en el MRU, MRUA y MCU, aplicando las ecuaciones adecuadas para obtener los valores del espacio recorrido, la velocidad y la aceleración.
\end{mytabenum} & CMCT, CCL, CAA.
\\
\midrule

\begin{mycontenidos}
\item Describir el MCUA y expresar la aceleración en función de sus componentes intrínsecas.
\end{mycontenidos}&

\begin{mytabenum}
\item Identifica las componentes intrínsecas de la aceleración en distintos casos prácticos y aplica las ecuaciones que permiten determinar su valor.
\end{mytabenum} & CMCT, CCL, CAA.
\\

\midrule

\begin{mycontenidos}
\item Relacionar en un movimiento circular las magnitudes angulares con las lineales. 
\end{mycontenidos}&

\begin{mytabenum}
\item Relaciona las magnitudes lineales y angulares para un móvil que describe unatrayectoria circular, estableciendo las ecuaciones correspondientes, y reconociendo situaciones cotidianas.
\end{mytabenum} & CMCT, CCL, CAA, CSC.
\\
\midrule

\begin{mycontenidos}
\item Identificar el movimiento no circular de un móvil en un plano como la composición de dos movimientos unidimensionales (MRU y MRUA). Utilizar aplicaciones virtuales interactivas de simulación de movimientos.
\end{mycontenidos}&

\begin{mytabenum}
\item Reconoce movimientos compuestos, establece las ecuaciones que los describen, calcula el valor de magnitudes como el alcance, la altura máxima, así como valores instantáneos de posición, velocidad y aceleración.
\item Resuelve problemas relativos a la composición de movimientos descomponiéndolos en dos movimientos rectilíneos.
\item Emplea simulaciones virtuales para resolver supuestos prácticos reales, determinando condiciones iniciales, trayectorias, y puntos de encuentro de los puntos implicados.
\end{mytabenum} & CCL, CAA.
\\
\bottomrule

\end{xltabular}}


\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks! But when I copy the code for the compact table, a lot of errors appear when I compiled, related to the enumitem package, such as **! Package enumitem Error: [ undefined.
See the enumitem package documentation for explanation.
Type H <return> for immediate help.
...
l.802 \end{xltabular}
}
Try typing <return> to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type X <return> to quit.**

Comment: Did, ou also copy the definition of the mycontenidos environment? After posting my answer to your previous question I slightly modifies the syntax of this environment. You probably still have the old definition in your document.