# Longtable with tabularx and mytabenum environments

Tags: longtable, enumerate, tabularx

I am building a table with the tabularx and mytabenum environments, but it is too long to fit in a single page. I´ve tried to use the longtable package, but I didn´t manage to fix the problem.

[image]

Here are the packages from the preambule:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[letterpaper, left=2.4cm, right=2.4cm, top=2.4cm, bottom=2.4cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[tight,footnotesize]{subfigure}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\newtcolorbox{mybox}{colback=green!3,colframe=green!75!black}
\newtcolorbox{mybox2}{,colback=blue!3!white,colframe=blue!75!black}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newlength\mylen
\settowidth\mylen{\textbf{Propuesta de}} % desired width of left-hand column
\usepackage{caption} 
\captionsetup[table]{skip=12pt}
\usepackage{float}
\definecolor{Gray}{gray}{0.9}
\usepackage{color, colortbl}
\definecolor{green}{HTML}{66FF66}
\definecolor{myGreen}{HTML}{009900}
\usepackage{booktabs}    
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{tabenum}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[tabenum]{label*=\arabic*.,
                  leftmargin=*,
                  nosep,
                  before=\begin{minipage}{\hsize},
                  after=\end{minipage}}
\newlist{contenidos}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[contenidos]{label*=\arabic*.,
                     leftmargin=*,
                     nosep,
                     before=\begin{minipage}{\hsize},
                     after=\end{minipage}}
\newenvironment{mytabenum}
               {\begin{tabenum}[label*=\thecurrentcontenidos.\arabic*.]}
               {\end{tabenum}}
\newenvironment{mycontenidos}
               [1][resume]
               {\begin{contenidos}[#1=contenidos] }
               {\setcounter{currentcontenidos}{\value{contenidosi}}\end{contenidos}}
               
\newcounter{currentcontenidos}
\usepackage{xltabular}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\normalsize\bfseries\color{myGreen}}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}
\usepackage{lscape} 
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{ltablex}
```

And here it is found the code for the table:

```
\begin{table}[H]
{\setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}
\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{@{} 
       p{5cm} 
       X  
       >{\centering\arraybackslash}p{\widthof{\textbf{Competencias}}}@{}}
\caption{Criterios, Estándares, y Competencias Clave asociadas.}
\label{tab:Crit,Est,CC}\\
\arrayrulecolor{green}
\toprule
\thead{Criterios de Evaluación} & \thead{Estándares Aprendizaje} & \thead{Competencias\\ Clave} \\
\midrule
\arrayrulecolor{black}
\endfirsthead
\arrayrulecolor{green}
\toprule
\thead{Criterios de Evaluación} & \thead{Estándares Aprendizaje} & \thead{Competencias\\ Clave} \\
\midrule
\arrayrulecolor{black}
\endhead
\begin{mycontenidos}[series]
\item Reconocer e identificar las
características del método
científico.
\end{mycontenidos} & 

\begin{mytabenum}
\item Formula hipótesis para explicar
fenómenos cotidianos utilizando
teorías y modelos científicos. 

\item Registra observaciones, datos y
resultados de manera organizada y
rigurosa, y los comunica de forma
oral y escrita utilizando esquemas,
gráficos, tablas y expresiones
matemáticas.
\end{mytabenum} & CMCT.
\\
\midrule
\begin{mycontenidos}
\item  Valorar la investigación científica
y su impacto en la industria y en el
desarrollo de la sociedad.
\end{mycontenidos} & 

\begin{mytabenum}
\item Relaciona la investigación
científica con las aplicaciones
tecnológicas en la vida cotidiana
\end{mytabenum} & CCL, CSC.
\\
\midrule

\begin{mycontenidos}
\item Conocer los procedimientos
científicos para determinar
magnitudes, uso de factores de
conversión y notación científica. 
\end{mycontenidos}&  

\begin{mytabenum}
\item Establece relaciones entre
magnitudes y unidades utilizando,
preferentemente, el Sistema
Internacional de Unidades y la
notación científica para expresar los
resultados.
\end{mytabenum} & CMCT.
\\
\midrule

\begin{mycontenidos}
\item Reconocer los materiales e
instrumentos básicos presentes del
laboratorio de Física y de Química;
conocer y respetar las normas de
seguridad y de eliminación de
residuos para la protección del
medioambiente. 
\end{mycontenidos}&

\begin{mytabenum}
\item Identifica material e
instrumentos básicos de laboratorio
y conoce su forma de utilización
para la realización de experiencias
respetando las normas de
seguridad e identificando actitudes y
medidas de actuación preventivas. 

\end{mytabenum} & CCL, CMCT, CAA, CSC.
\\
\midrule

\begin{mycontenidos}
\item  Interpretar la información sobre
temas científicos de carácter
divulgativo que aparece en
publicaciones y medios de
comunicación.
\end{mycontenidos}&

\begin{mytabenum}
\item Selecciona, comprende e
interpreta información relevante en
un texto de divulgación científica y
transmite las conclusiones
obtenidas utilizando el lenguaje oral
y escrito con propiedad.
\item Identifica las principales
características ligadas a la fiabilidad
y objetividad del flujo de información
existente en internet y otros medios
digitales.
\end{mytabenum} &  CCL, CSC.
\\
\midrule

\begin{mycontenidos}
\item Desarrollar pequeños trabajos de
investigación y presentar el informe
correspondiente, en los que se
ponga en práctica la aplicación del
método científico y la utilización de
las TIC.
\end{mycontenidos}&

\begin{mytabenum}
\item Realiza pequeños trabajos de
investigación sobre algún tema
objeto de estudio aplicando el
método científico, y utiliza las TIC
para la búsqueda y selección de
información y presentación de
conclusiones en un informe. 
\item Participa, valora, gestiona y
respeta el trabajo individual y en
equipo.
\end{mytabenum} & CCL, CMCT, CD, SIEP.
\\

\bottomrule

\end{xltabular}}
\end{table}
```

Comment: It's a mistake to encase an `xltabular` in a `table` environment. Remove the `\begin{table}` and `\end{table}` directives and recompile.

Comment: What's wrong with the code in [my previous answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/584052/134144)? There I already showed you how to use `xltabular` in order to make sure the table spans multiple pages.